# How to query mongo using virtual attributes from Collection.transform in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Lets say I have 3 collections `Customers`, `Contacts`, and `Messages`

```
Customers {_id, name, address, city, state, zip}
Contacts {_id, customer_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone}
Messages {_id, contact_id, subject, body}
```

Ok now I have a setup some attributes and methods on each of these collections to bring in the related collections as a function that can get called directly on an instance of the document via transform to give me the ability to daisy chain in my templates like `{{#each contact}}{{customer.name}}{{/each}}` here is how I am transforming them.

```
Contact.prototype = {
    constructor: Contact,

    customer: function () {
        return Customers.findOne({_id: this.customer_id});
    },

    fullName: function () {
        return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name;
    }, 

    neverContacted: function () {
        if (!Messages.findOne({contact_id: this._id})) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    }
};
```

and

```
Customer.prototype = {
    constructor: Customer,

    owner: function () {
        user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.user_id});
        return user.username || user.emails[0].address;
    }, 

    contacts: function () {
        contacts = Contacts.find({customer_id: this._id}).fetch();
        return contacts;
    }
};
```

My question is how can I make a say a my query the customers collection based on a virtual attribute of the customers collection

like `customers.find().contacts().neverContacted()`

kinda like active record style of daisy chaining?;

Comment: customers.find().forEach(function(item){ item.neverContacted() });

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would get all "contacts" out of this, perhaps in an inefficient way:

```
var allContacts = [];
customers.find().forEach(function(customer){ 
     var contacts = customer.neverContacted(); 
     contacts.forEach(function(contact){
          allContacts.push(contact); //You will want to have an if here to check if it already contains that contact already.
     });
});
```

Another option:

```
setupSearches(customers.find()).contacts()

setupSearches = function(input){
     input.contacts = function () {
        contacts = input.find({customer_id: this._id}).fetch();
        return contacts;
     }
     return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably no one has answered this because there are a lot of steps involved and different ways to solve it.

I can tell you how to start: You need to rewrite your class with a strategy that permits you to return the "this" keyword in the functions.  For example, you could store results into a result property, then test if the result property is populated to do maninupulations in other functions.

e.g.

```
//how you might get the results
customers.find().contacts().neverContacted().result
//in the prototype
contacts: function () {
        this.result = Contacts.find({customer_id: this._id}).fetch();
        return this;
}
//in the other prototype
neverContacted: function () {
    if(this.result){
    // do something special and return
    }
    if (!Messages.findOne({contact_id: this._id})) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
}
```

Second, you need customer to inherit from contacts or the same base class perhaps.

Once you do that, store your result set in a property

This question is rather confusing, are you extending a collection?

Then you might use the underscore _.extend().

More concrete question, I'll try to give a better answer.